# how to set network configuration for vm in esx host through command?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere, esx

I am trying to automate setting network configuration(setting IP address, netmask, gateway) to already created Linux VM in an ESX host.

I need a **vSphere** CLI command to automate it.

Can you please help me out?

Thanks,
NagaPavan

Answer (score 0):

Check this one :-
https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/Set-VMGuestNetworkInterface.html

Let me know if that help.